# Modify in a crud table

Tags: reactjs, crud

Iam new to programming i started with frontend and React js iam creating a CRUD Table i want to modify when i console.log the id it gives me the right id however my data is not being updated for some reason that i'm unaware of.

This is my code i'am going to only includ my add and update because i'm sure the problem is with them colliding or something

```
const UserNewDevice = () => {
    // I use Those to create a new product
    const [typeDuBien, setTypeDuBien] = useState([]);
    const [produits, setProduits] = useState('');
    const [annéeInstallation, setAnnéeInstallation] = useState('');
    const [marque, setMarque] = useState('');
    const [référence, setRéférence] = useState('');
    const [photoDuProduit, setPhotoDuProduit] = useState(null);
    const [entretenu, setEntretenu] = useState('');   
    const [selectedYearEntretenu, setSelectedYearEntretenu] = useState("");
    const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    const years = Array.from({length: 20}, (_, i) => currentYear - i);
    const [selectedYear, setSelectedYear] = useState(currentYear);
    // I Use Those to modify
    const [produitsModify, setProduitsModify] = useState('');
    const [annéeInstallationModify, setAnnéeInstallationModify] = useState('');
    const [marqueModify, setMarqueModify] = useState('');
    const [référenceModify, setRéférenceModify] = useState('');
    const [photoDuProduitModify, setPhotoDuProduitModify] = useState('');
    const [entretenuModify, setEntretenuModify] = useState('');
    const [selectedYearEntretenuModify, setSelectedYearEntretenuModify] = useState('');
    const [typeDuBienModify, setTypeDuBienModify] = useState([]);    
    const [selectedYearModify, setSelectedYearModify] = useState(currentYear);

  

const [isModifyModalVisible, setIsModifyModalVisible] = useState(false);
const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(null); 
const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false); 
const [pendingList, setPendingList] = useState([]);
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
const [error, setError] = useState('');
const email = localStorage.getItem("email")     



//Fetch request to modify a product
const handleModifyProduct = async (id) => {
    const formData = {
        annéeInstallation: annéeInstallationModify,
        marque: marqueModify,
        référence: référenceModify,
        selectedYearEntretenu: selectedYearEntretenuModify,
        produits: newProduitsModify,
    };        
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/prods/modify_product', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ id: id, formData}),
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
};    
    
const handleDataChange = (newData) => {
    setPendingList(newData);
};`
```

and this is my Modify modal

```
    {isModifyModalVisible ? (
        <>
            <div className="fixed inset-0 z-10 overflow-y-auto">
                <div
                    className="fixed inset-0 w-full h-full bg-black opacity-40"
                    onClick={() => setIsModalVisible(false)}
                ></div>
                <div className="flex items-center min-h-screen px-4 py-8">
                    <div className="relative w-full max-w-lg p-4 mx-auto bg-white rounded-md shadow-lg">
                        <div className="mt-3 sm:flex">
                            <div className="flex items-center justify-center flex-none w-12 h-12 mx-auto bg-yellow-100 rounded-full">
                                <IoAddCircleOutline className='text-yellow-600'/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="mt-2 text-center sm:ml-4 sm:text-left">
                                <h4 className="text-lg font-medium text-gray-800">
                                    Modifier votre appareil
                                </h4>
                                <p className="mt-2 text-[15px] leading-relaxed text-gray-500 mb-4">
                                    Veuillez remplir toutes les informations requises dans le formulaire pour modifier votre appareil.
                                </p>
                                <div className="modal-content mr-4">
                                    <form className='mr-4 mb-4'>
                                        <div>
                                            <fieldset>
                                            <legend className="contents text-base font-medium text-gray-900 ">Produits installés</legend>
                                            {/*<p className="text-sm text-gray-500">These are delivered via SMS to your mobile phone.</p>*/}
                                            <div className="mt-4 space-y-4">
                                                <div className="flex items-center">
                                                <input
                                                    id="typeDuBien"
                                                    name=" Pompe à chaleur"
                                                    type="radio"
                                                    value="Pompe à chaleur"
                                                    checked={produitsModify && produitsModify === "Pompe à chaleur"}                            
                                                    onChange={handleProduitsModify}
                                                    className="h-4 w-4 border-gray-300 text-indigo-600 focus:ring-indigo-500"
                                                />
                                                <label htmlFor="push-everything" className="ml-3 block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                                                    Pompe à chaleur
                                                </label>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="flex items-center">
                                                <input
                                                    id="push-email"
                                                    name="push-notifications"
                                                    type="radio"
                                                    value="ballon thermodynamique"
                                                    checked={produitsModify && produitsModify === "ballon thermodynamique"}
                                                    onChange={handleProduitsModify}
                                                    className="h-4 w-4 border-gray-300 text-indigo-600 focus:ring-indigo-500"
                                                />
                                                <label htmlFor="push-email" className="ml-3 block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                                                    ballon thermodynamique
                                                </label>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="flex items-center">
                                                    <input
                                                        id="push-nothing"
                                                        name="push-notifications"
                                                        type="radio"
                                                        value="ballon solaire"
                                                        checked={produitsModify === "ballon solaire"}
                                                        onChange={handleProduitsModify}                            
                                                        className="h-4 w-4 border-gray-300 text-indigo-600 focus:ring-indigo-500"
                                                    />
                                                    <label htmlFor="push-nothing" className="ml-3 block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                                                        ballon solaire
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="flex items-center">
                                                    <input
                                                        id="push-nothing"
                                                        name="push-notifications"
                                                        type="checkbox"
                                                        value="ballon d’eau chaude électrique"
                                                        checked={produitsModify && produitsModify.includes("ballon d’eau chaude électrique")}
                                                        onChange={handleProduitsModify}                            
                                                        className="h-4 w-4 border-gray-300 text-indigo-600 focus:ring-indigo-500"
                                                    />
                                                    <label htmlFor="push-nothing" className="ml-3 block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                                                        ballon d’eau chaude électrique
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>                                                        
                                            </div>
                                            </fieldset>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="relative mt-4">
                                            <label htmlFor="annéeInstallation" className="sr-only">
                                                Année d’installation
                                            </label>
                                            <select
                                                id="annéeInstallation"
                                                name="annéeInstallation"
                                                value={annéeInstallationModify}
                                                onChange={e => setAnnéeInstallationModify(e.target.value)}
                                                className="block appearance-none w-full bg-white border border-gray-300 hover:border-gray-300 px-4 py-2 pr-8 rounded  leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline cursor-pointer"
                                            >
                                                {years.map(year => (
                                                    <option key={year} value={year}>
                                                        {year}
                                                    </option>
                                                ))}
                                            </select>
                                            <div className="pointer-events-none absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center px-2 text-gray-700">
                                                <svg
                                                className="fill-current h-4 w-4"
                                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                                viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                                                >
                                                <path d="M9.293 12.95l.707.707L15.657 8l-1.414-1.414L10 10.828 5.757 6.586 4.343 8z" />
                                                </svg>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                        <label htmlFor="marque" className="sr-only ">
                                            Marque de produit
                                        </label>
                                        <input
                                            id="marque"
                                            name="marque"
                                            type="text"
                                            autoComplete="marque"
                                            value={marqueModify} 
                                            onChange={e => setMarqueModify(e.target.value)}                         
                                            required
                                            style={{marginTop: '16px'}}
                                            className="relative p-16 block w-full appearance-none rounded-lg border border-gray-300 px-3 py-2 text-gray-900 placeholder-gray-500 focus:z-10 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 sm:text-sm"
                                            placeholder="Marque de produit"
                                        />
                                        </div>   
                                        <div>
                                        <label htmlFor="référence" className="sr-only ">
                                            référence
                                        </label>
                                        <input
                                            id="référence"
                                            name="aréférence"
                                            type="text"
                                            autoComplete="référence"
                                            required
                                            value={référenceModify} 
                                            onChange={e => setRéférenceModify(e.target.value)}                                                
                                            style={{marginTop: '16px'}}
                                            className="relative p-16 block w-full appearance-none rounded-lg border border-gray-300 px-3 py-2 text-gray-900 placeholder-gray-500 focus:z-10 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 sm:text-sm"
                                            placeholder="Référence"
                                        />
                                        </div>   
                                        <div>
                                        <label className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700" style={{marginTop: '16px'}}>Photo du produit</label>
                                        </div>  
                                        <fieldset className='mb-6 margin-top'>
                                            <legend className="contents text-sm font-medium text-gray-600">Votre produit est entretenu</legend>
                                            <div className="mt-4 space-y-4">
                                                <div className="flex items-center">
                                                    <input
                                                    id="oui"
                                                    name="entretenu"
                                                    type="radio"
                                                    value="oui"
                                                    onChange={e => setEntretenuModify(e.target.value)}
                                                    checked={entretenuModify&& entretenuModify.includes("oui")}                        
                                                    className="h-4 w-4 border-gray-300 text-indigo-600 focus:ring-indigo-500"
                                                    />
                                                    <label htmlFor="oui" className="ml-3 block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                                                    Oui
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="flex items-center">
                                                    <input
                                                    id="non"
                                                    name="entretenu"
                                                    type="radio"
                                                    className="h-4 w-4 border-gray-300 text-indigo-600 focus:ring-indigo-500"
                                                    value="non"
                                                    onChange={e => setEntretenuModify(e.target.value)}  
                                                    checked={entretenuModify&& entretenuModify.includes("non")}   
                                                                        
                                                    
                                                    />
                                                    <label htmlFor="non" className="ml-3 block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                                                    Non
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </fieldset>   
                                        {entretenu === "oui" && (
                                            <div className="relative mt-4">
                                            <label htmlFor="annéeInstallation" className="sr-only">
                                                Année d’installation
                                            </label>
                                            <select
                                                id="annéeInstallation"
                                                name="annéeInstallation"
                                                value={selectedYearEntretenuModify}
                                                onChange={e => setSelectedYearModify(e.target.value)}
                                                className="block appearance-none w-full bg-white border border-gray-300 hover:border-gray-300 px-4 py-2 pr-8 rounded  leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline cursor-pointer"
                                            >
                                                {years.map(year => (
                                                    <option key={year} value={year}>
                                                        {year}
                                                    </option>
                                                ))}
                                            </select>
                                            <div className="pointer-events-none absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center px-2 text-gray-700">
                                                <svg
                                                className="fill-current h-4 w-4"
                                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                                viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                                                >
                                                <path d="M9.293 12.95l.707.707L15.657 8l-1.414-1.414L10 10.828 5.757 6.586 4.343 8z" />
                                                </svg>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
    )}                                                                                         
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                <div className="items-center gap-2 mt-3 sm:flex pb-4 mr-4">
                                    <button
                                        className="w-full mt-2 p-2.5 flex-1 text-white bg-green-600 rounded-md outline-none ring-offset-2 ring-red-600 focus:ring-2"
                                        onClick={handleConfirmModify}
                                    >
                                        Modifier
                                    </button>
                                    <button
                                        className="w-full mt-2 p-2.5 flex-1 text-gray-800 rounded-md outline-none border ring-offset-2 ring-indigo-600 focus:ring-2"
                                        onClick={handleCancelModify}
                                        
                                    >
                                        Cancel
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    ) : null}
```

I think the problem is with the way i'm handeling my data I'm not sure tho, also i'm new to stackoverflow so sorry for the block of codes

Comment: You don't do anything with the `data` variable. You never use `handleDataChange` for example